# Strange folder in trash does not delete even in safe mode

Tags: macos, finder, trash

I have a very strange folder in trash that cannot be deleted, even in safe mode. It looks like this: 
a/b/a/b/a/b/a/b/a/b... 
[image]

"STM32NucleoPowerControl is the name of my old programming project I don't need anymore. Maybe this odd structure was generated by some crazy IDE? When I try to delete this folder, Finder says that the folder cannot be deleted because item "gcc" is in use. When I skip it, item "ARM" is in use, and so on with other files. Therefore, I have to skip all these files every time when I empty the trash. Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried removing the top folder from the command line as root?

Comment: Another option is an app called “trash it” - 3rd party but not mine and that works...

Comment: Can you open Terminal, run `cd .Trash; ls -lid STM32* STM32/* STM32/*/*` and add the result to the question (copy/paste as text)?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to use `rm -r` on the directory without root.